# "PHP Parse error..." when trying to run phpunit.phar

Tags: installation, phpunit

I am trying to set up phpunit on my server.  This is what I did so far...

1. SSH into Apache server via PuTTY
2. Ran command... `cd /path/to`
3. Ran command... `wget http://pear.phpunit.de/get/phpunit.phar`
4. Ran command... `chmod +x phpunit.phar`
5. Ran command... `/path/to/phpunit.phar`

The error I received is...

`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in /path/to/phpunit.phar on line 6`

The first 8 lines of the phpunit.phar file are...

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
define('__PHPUNIT_PHAR__', realpath($GLOBALS['_SERVER']['SCRIPT_NAME']));

spl_autoload_register(
  function ($class)
  {
      static $classes = NULL;
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Bah, that must be it!  Can't believe I forgot to check.  The earliest phpunit.phar seems to only work with 5.3.3+, but the server I'm working on right now is at v5.2.17.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [at least PHP 5.3.3](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html) to use PHPUnit's phar version:

> Note: 
>   PHPUnit 3.7 requires PHP 5.3.3 (or later) but PHP 5.4.7 (or later) is highly recommended.